# Sampling a vector (v1) to create a new one (v1), but where the number in v2 position i must be different to that in v1

Tags: r, vector

I'm working with a vector like this:

```
V1 <- seq(1:21)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

And sampling it to create a new vector without replacement, v2, where there is some probability that numbers <  10 will 'migrate' to the second half of the new vector (i.e., they will take on a number > 10)

```
v2 <- sample(v1, prob = ifelse(v1 <=10, 0.97, 0.03))
[1]  4 15  2  6  9  5  1  8 10 12  3  7 20 21 13 19 18 17 11 14 16
```

But I need to impose an additional condition: the number in position i of v2 cannot be the same as position i in v1. As an example, in the above position 8 in v1 and v2 both have the same number, which should not be the case. I ideally, this solution would work without the numbers in v1 being consecutive.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated!

Sean

Comment: probably not a very practical idea, but you could input it into a `while()` loop and resample it until no matches are found. you can test this with `table(v1 %in% v2)`. set `if (table(v1 %in% v2)[[2]]==0)` as a stop condition to the loop and you have a non matching sample

Comment: Thanks, but Im not sure this makes sense. for the test condition you mention using table(v1 %in% v2), but every number is present in both vectors. Maybe Im missing something? Id really appreciate it if you could explain this a bit further...

Comment: @D.J's idea is right but the test is wrong.  Use `all(v1 != v2)` as the indicator of success.  The loop should stop fairly quickly:  this is the "Matching Problem".

Comment: yes @user2554330 is correct. his way is faster and easier. also the `%in%` in my comment is of course wrong. it works with `table(v1 == v2)[[2]]==0` which is still an unnecessarily complicated step compared to `all(v1 != v2)`.